# joint autoencoder with sharing weight using keras

Tags: keras

In this [article](http://article), I've come across the following network structure:

[image]

Figure 1(b). https://wx4.sinaimg.cn/mw690/5396ee05ly1fg9vi5phcbj20vj0kb0ty.jpg

Each layer is a fully connected one.

**The weights shared by the two parts are denoted by Wc**.

The pairs of the top fully connected layers of dimension 500 are concatenated to create a layer of dimension 1000 which is then used directly to reconstruct the input of size 784.

I want to implement it with keras, however I am not skilled with `keras`.

any ideas on how to implement this?

thank you very much!